# instead of using import { a, b } from 'some-lib', what is the equivalent using require?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been using babel and never really thought about this.

In my own modules, I'm exporting multiple modules and I'm able to do something like `var something = require('something-i-made');` and then `something.thingA`.

However, what about when using something from a library like react-router?

What would be the correct way to use require in place of `import { RouterContext, match } from 'react-router';`?

Comment: You could look at the transpiled code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement

```
import { foo, bar, baz as abc } from 'my-module';
```

is (by using [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), in Node 6 or newer) roughly equivalent to

```
const { foo, bar, baz: abc } = require('my-module');
```

or (for older versions of node):

```
var myModule = require('my-module');
var foo = myModule.foo;
var bar = myModule.bar;
var abc = myModule.baz;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use ES6 object destructuring:

```
const { RouterContext, match } = require('react-router')
```

If the above is unsupported you can fallback to just accessing the properties as usual:

```
var Router = require('react-router');
var RouterContext = Router.RouterContext;
var match = Router.match;
```

Comment: Note that since imported variables are read-only, it would probably be more accurate to use `const` than `let`.

Comment: Yup, I agree  fully!